# Как перемещать второй элемент при движении первого?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Есть два div c одинаковыми размерами, но в разных местах.
Есть код который запускает drag на эти элементы.

```
$(function() {
    $('.div1, .div2').draggable({
      axis: 'x',
      cursor: 'pointer',
      cursorAt: 'pointer',
      drag: function(event, ui) {
        var left = ui.position.left,
            offsetWidth = ($(this).width() - $(this).parent().width()) * -1;

        if (left > 0) {
          ui.position.left = 0;
        }
        if (offsetWidth > left) {
          ui.position.left = offsetWidth;
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при перетаскивании первого div1, автоматически перетаскивался второй и наоборот.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать .on( "dragstart/dragstop", function( event, ui ) {} );